# Can't find working speech recognition for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I'm trying to add speech recognition to my Unity project. I tried `Microsoft.Speech.dll` which I used before for writing my own voice assistant, but it requires `sysglobl.dll`. If I add it, Unity shows this error:

> "Loading assembly failed: "Assets/Libraries/sysblobl.dll".

I also tried using `Unity.Speech.Recognition`, but it's for Windows 10 only (I have Windows 8.1). So, any other ideas? Libs or something else? Because Google gives only these two options.